# speak failed:not bound to tts engine

Tags: java, android, eclipse, email, text-to-speech

Issue : speak failed:not bound to `tts engine`

I am implementing `textToSpeech` functionality. I am getting the exception as speak failed: not bound to `tts engine`. I am implementing the `async task` with it. the `async task` will be reading the `mail`. And i want to convert the `mail body to speech`.

```
package com.example.trynot;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.Menu;
import java.util.Locale;

import com.example.trynot.MainActivity.ReadMailSample;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.speech.tts.TextToSpeech;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
public class Notify extends Activity implements TextToSpeech.OnInitListener {
/** Called when the activity is first created. */


public TextToSpeech tts = new TextToSpeech(MainActivity.c, Notify.this);

 public Notify()
 {
     System.out.println("Inside Constructor");
     speakOut();
 }

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
// Don't forget to shutdown tts!
if (tts != null) {
    tts.stop();
    tts.shutdown();
}
super.onDestroy();
}

@Override
public void onInit(int status) {
System.out.println("inside INIT");
if (status == TextToSpeech.SUCCESS) {

    int result = tts.setLanguage(Locale.US);
    tts.speak(MainActivity.ReadMailSample.command, TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, null);
    if (result == TextToSpeech.LANG_MISSING_DATA
            || result == TextToSpeech.LANG_NOT_SUPPORTED) {
        Log.e("TTS", "This Language is not supported");
    } else {

        speakOut();
    }

} else {
    Log.e("TTS", "Initilization Failed!");
}

}

private void speakOut() {
    System.out.println("inside SPeak out");
tts.speak(MainActivity.ReadMailSample.command, TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, null);
}


}
```

Comment: Can you post the stacktrace?

Answer (score 1):

You should move instatiation of tts engine instance to onCreate, this line:

```
public TextToSpeech tts = new TextToSpeech(MainActivity.c, Notify.this);
```

change to:

```
public TextToSpeech tts;
```

and add inside your `onCreate`:

```
    tts = new TextToSpeech(MainActivity.c, Notify.this);
```

And - whats most important - do not use constructor in Activity derived classes:

```
 public Notify()
 {
     System.out.println("Inside Constructor");
     speakOut();
 }
```

should be your onCreate:

```
 @Override
 protected void onCreate (Bundle savedInstanceState)
 {
     super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
     //speakOut(); // here tts is not yet initialized, call it in onInit on success
     //tts = new TextToSpeech(MainActivity.c, Notify.this); // whats MainActivity.c?
     tts = new TextToSpeech(this, this);
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

your google text to speech engine may be disable... once check it on your setting

if it is disable it also shows the same error